# FancyBox parent moves when slider images are clicked within the fancybox itself

Tags: jquery, fancybox, slideshow, carousel

This is how i link to my fancybox:

```
<div id="border">
    <a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="paincenter.php" title="">
        <span id="thumbnail_left">  
            <img src="assets/img/paincenter_338.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='assets/img/paincenter_magnify_338.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='assets/img/paincenter_338.jpg'" />
        </span>
        <h2 class="heading">Pain Center</h2>
    </a>
        <p>
            At The Pain Center, our specialists offer a variety of treatments to Get You Back Into Life! We are committed to working with you on the pain-related issues that matter <a class="iframe" href="paincenter.php" title="">more...</a>                                   
        </p>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the slider inside my linked fancybox:

```
<div id="wowslider-container1" class="left">

    <div class="ws_images">
        <ul>
            <li><img src="assets/data1/images/paincenter.jpg" alt="" title="" id="wows1_0"/></li>
            <li><img src="assets/data1/images/paincenter_techniques.jpg" alt="" title="" id="wows1_1"/></li>
            <li><img src="assets/data1/images/paincenter_injection.jpg" alt="" title="" id="wows1_2"/></li>
            <li><img src="assets/data1/images/paincenter_contact.jpg" alt="" title="" id="wows1_3"/></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="ws_thumbs">
        <a href="#wows1_0" title=""><img src="assets/data1/tooltips/paincenter.jpg" alt="" /></a>
        <a href="#wows1_1" title=""><img src="assets/data1/tooltips/paincenter_techniques.jpg" alt="" /></a>
        <a href="#wows1_2" title=""><img src="assets/data1/tooltips/paincenter_injection.jpg" alt="" /></a>
        <a href="#wows1_3" title=""><img src="assets/data1/tooltips/paincenter_contact.jpg" alt="" /></a>
    </div>

</div>
```

When any of the thumbs are clicked the page which my fancybox is hovered over moves down till it gets to the bottom of the page?? My fancybox doesnt move at all but it is really distracting seeing your main page move behind your FancyBox.

```
/*** Page Reset ***/
html, body, div, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, ul, ol, dl, li, dt, dd, p, blockquote, pre, form,    fieldset, table, th, td {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
/*** Main ***/
body {
font-size: 13px;
font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-weight: lighter;
background-color: #ffffff;
min-width: 1024px;
}
```

Comment: what is the js code you are using? what version of fancybox? are you applying css rules to general elements like `html` and `body`?

Comment: Im using 2.1.4 Fancybox - The reason I believe it is my slider is because I was using lightbox and it was doing this so i switched to fancybox thinking Id get better results

Comment: please edit your question and add the code there, not in the comments area

Comment: @JFK I have added my main css classes

Comment: I wouldn't set dimensions to the `body` tag but use a wrapper (`div`) container instead ... `width: 100%;` will always be relative to the viewport with unexpected behavior if resizing the window. Try removing `width`, `height` and `min-width` from `body` and you'll see your issue fixed

Comment: So i took away the elements to the body tag and added a wrapper div, took away the width height min-width stuff and it didn't work.

Comment: Can you share a link?

Comment: nothing is live yet sadly

Comment: Just a guess, maybe you are clicking navigation arrows?